# Excel: Search for if a cell contains any of the values from a list of possible values and return all that matched (in a cell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For my Excel sheet, I'd like to create a column that searches a cell from a specific list of values and displays all the values that were contained in it.

[image: Example of what I want the columns to show]

I have a column with "instructions" that mention certain document names within them. In another column, I want to show all the document names that were detected from the instructions column. There is a separate column (not shown) that contains a master list of all possible documents, from which the search is based off of.

At the current moment, I have an extremely long formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!F$3, I4)), Sheet2!F$3& CHAR(10), 
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!F$4, I4)), Sheet2!F$4& CHAR(10),  
 IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!F$5, I4)), Sheet2!F$5& CHAR(10),  .... etc.
```

The biggest problem is that it only returns one of the values (Document names), in addition to being very long and inefficient.

I've also tried using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F18:F20, H19)))>0
```

But this only returns a `TRUE`/`FALSE` and not all the values.

I'd like to be able to search using an array of the document column and return all the values that were contained in the "instructions" cells.

I've looked at multiple related questions on stackoverflow, but I couldn't find one that was able to link the different elements of multiple value search (from array and its containment in a cell), multiple value return (in a single cell). I definitely don't want to hard code the values into the formula either, so how would you approach this?

Comment: How does your algorithm work so as to return `AnalysisA` in `B3` but not in `B2`?

Comment: Hi Ron, good catch, that was a typo, AnalysisA should be shown in B2 too! This example was not formula based (I just typed values in).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!F$3:F$10,I4)),Sheet2!F$3:F$10,""))
```

This is an array formula.  It requires that one confirms it with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

---

If you do not have Office 365 Excel then you can modify your long formula.  Do not nest the IFs but concatenate them and put the `CHAR(10)` before each. like so:

```
=MID(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!F$3, I4)), CHAR(10) & Sheet2!F$3,"") &
     IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!F$4, I4)), CHAR(10) & Sheet2!F$4,"") &
     IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!F$5, I4)), CHAR(10) & Sheet2!F$5,"") & ...,2,999)
```

Where the `...` is the rest of the list.

Comment: Hi Scott! Thanks so much for your help! I'm not very familiar with Excel so your answer is highly appreciated. A few questions: (1) I attempted using TEXTJOIN but it returned "FALSEFALSEFALSE...etc." Can it return the actual value instead? (2) I looked up the MID function and was wondering how we can determine what the start_num and num_chars are - does this function do that automatically? When I tried this formula, the result was blank. Thanks again!

Comment: If the result was blank there were no matches on the second.  The first has been fixed so the FALSEs will not populate. @Mandy

Comment: Since we add `Char(10) to every one that returns we want to drop the first Char(10) hence starting at character `2`.  The `999` assumes that the return string will not be larger that 999 characters. @Mandy